# Are multivariate probit models with the same set of explanatory variables for each outcome more efficient that piecewise probit regressions?

Tags: probit, multivariate-regression, seemingly-unrelated-regressions

I understand that multivariate probit models are analogous to SUR models. In the SUR case, there's no efficiency gain by fitting a SUR model over several independent OLS regressions when the model matrix is the same for each of the dependent variables. Is that also true for multivariate probit models, so there's no benefit to the more complex model in that case?

(Though, of course, directly estimating the correlation structure in the error term of the latent variable may be useful in and of itself.)